# What's the best way to keep track of changes to ROS stacks and packages?

Tags: ros, package, stacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Title says it all. News feed? Run rosinstall frequently? Something else?

macports has selfupdate, for example.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9416/what%27s-the-best-way-to-keep-track-of-changes-to-ros-stacks-and-packages?/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on what OS you are on. If Ubuntu, just use debs and let the package manager handle it. If something else, running rosinstall is probably the best way to make sure you are up to date.

Subscribing to the ros-users list is also an excellent way to keep track of important changes, as they are often announced there before they happen.

There was talk of perhaps making something like a "ros-announce" list that would likely be moderated and would only handle important announcements (such as the change from `setup.sh` to `setup.bash`) so that they don't get lost in the sometimes high-traffic ros-users list.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on 2011-03-15**:
a ros-announce list sounds like a good idea. Or maybe just a page on the website listing updated packages and the like?